# has_many :through and acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, acts-as-taggable-on

How can I get all the tags for a model's associated models using `acts-as-taggable-on`?

I have the following models, and want to build a list of tags that the network's associated offers have:

```
class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :offers
end

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  belongs_to  :network
end
```

How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@network.offers.map{|o| o.tags }.flatten.compact
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looping over Network.tag_counts.